# Latex: Glossary Tiny Header

Tags: glossaries

I created an abbreviation list thanks to `glossaries` and I declare it in my preamble before the `\begin{document}` this way:

```
\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries}
\makeglossaries
```

Then I want to get "List of abbreviations" instead of "Glossary" so after the `\begin{document}` I write the command:

```
\renewcommand{\glossaryname}{List of abbreviations}
```

So far no problem, but when I compile my document in the header it writes me "List of abbreviations", however the rest of my headers is capitalized. So I would like to know how to capitalize this title in the header.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Try package option `ucmark`, but it would help if you provided a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that showed the document class.